# JpaRepository.save() generates hql inserting null values into the tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring boot+ hibernates+mysql application I have my own `UserRepository` :

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
```

And I have a `user` table in `mysql` database, and a corresponding entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator. This field corresponds to the database column user.id
     * @mbg.generated  Mon Sep 28 14:41:58 CST 2020
     */
    
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id",length=32) //
    private Integer id;
    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator. This field corresponds to the database column user.ori_id
     * @mbg.generated  Mon Sep 28 14:41:58 CST 2020
     */
    @Column(name="ori_id",length=32) //
    private Integer oriId;
    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator. This field corresponds to the database column user.user_name
     * @mbg.generated  Mon Sep 28 14:41:58 CST 2020
     */
    @Size(min = 3, max = 18, message = "Minimum user name length: 3 characters")
    @Column(name="user_name",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userName;
```

the `findAll` method works fine, but when I created a User object and call `save` method:

```
List<User> list=userRepository.findAll();  
userRepository.deleteAll();
User admin = new User();
admin.setUserName("admin");
admin.setPassword("admin");
admin.setEmail("admin@email.com");
admin.setCreateTime(new Date());
admin.setRole(Role.ROLE_ADMIN.name());
userRepository.save(admin);
```

the hql generated is:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        user
        (create_ime, email, last_user_ime, last_password_change, mobile, ori_id, password, real_name, role, role_id, status, user_count, user_name, user_ime) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

which seems that the `save` method is saving a object with all fields `null` and I got the error:

```
2020-09-30 10:24:24.657  WARN 15956 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2020-09-30 10:24:24.662 ERROR 15956 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'create_time' doesn't have a default value
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Only the fields that you do not provide a value for will be null.  The DB says that a value should be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (?, ?, ?, ...) is normal in hibernate logs, the actual parameter values are not logged, that doesn't mean that the inserted values are null.

Note that the query is inserting the field "create_ime" and the error says the column that does not accept nulls is "create_time", so it seems you have both columns in the table, probably caused by a typo correction or rename.